# I am trying to find the geometric mean in c++ using object oriented programming

Tags: c++, oop

So I'm trying to find the geometric mean I believe I have the function correct... I get an error that says I need to define `pow`... Do I make a separate function or what? This is the code I have already tried.

```
float MyCollection::GM(){
    float aux=0;
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        aux*=series[i];
    }
    return((double)(pow(aux),(series[i]/n)));              
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, edit your code like @NathanOliver said. For maths, you have made two mistakes:

1. Your `aux` will always be `0`.
2. The exponent should be `1/n` according to the definition of [Geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).

The main calculation should be:

```
float aux = 1.0f;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    aux *= series[i];
}
return pow(aux, 1.0/n);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `pow` you need to include `math.h` or `cmath`.

You also have a typo.  in

```
return((double)(pow(aux),(series[i]/n)));
```

you are only calling the `pow` function with one argument

```
pow(aux)
```

I believe you ment to have

```
return pow(aux, series[I]/n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following header file

```
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

cmath.pow takes 2 arguments
Do you actually mean "return (double)(pow(aux,(series[i]/n)));"?